# ¿Cuál podría ser una palabra para referirse a alguien que desea algo pero prefiere ignorarlo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Contexto: "una persona quiere cambiar de trabajo y puede hacerlo, pero prefiere seguir en el mismo".

(No es conformismo).

Comment: Depende de las razones que tenga para no hacer algo que quiere y puede hacer. Normalmente si uno puede y no lo hace es porque no quiere, así diga que si.

Answer (score 3):

Depende de la razón para ignorarlo. En el ejemplo, yo usaría **inercia**.

- Quería y podía cambiar de trabajo, pero por inercia me quedé en el mismo.

El DLE define [inercia](https://dle.rae.es/inercia?m=form) como

> 1. f. Fís. Propiedad de los cuerpos de mantener su estado de reposo o movimiento si no es por la acción de una fuerza.
> 2. f. Rutina, desidia.

pero es común usarlo en sentido figurado como "resistencia al cambio".

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre **perezoso**:

> 1. adj. Negligente, descuidado o flojo en hacer lo que debe o necesita ejecutar. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Tardo, lento o pesado en el movimiento o en la acción.

Answer (score 0):

> "Si una persona quiere cambiar de trabajo y puede hacerlo, pero prefiere seguir en el mismo". Y no es conformismo.

> ¿Cuál podría ser una palabra para referirse a alguien que desea algo pero prefiere ignorarlo?

La palabra ignorar me sugiere que está rechazando una oferta.

> ignorar. ‘No saber [algo], o no tener noticia [de ello]’.

La palabra obviar a que está eludiendo un problema.

> obviar. ‘Evitar o rehuir [un obstáculo o dificultad]’.

Y descartar lo mismo que ignorar, pero más a una cosa, es decir, descartar la posibilidad, en cambio al decir ignorar hay una persona involucrada o ignora la oferta hecha por esa entidad.

> descartar. ‘Rechazar o no tener en cuenta una posibilidad o circunstancia‘.

Si es por miedo entonces temeroso.

> temeroso, sa 1. adj. Medroso, irresoluto. 2. adj. Que recela un daño.

Si es porque está seguro en su trabajo actual y quiere ir pero está analizando los pros y contras o prefiere ignorar la oferta porque no le conviene: cauteloso, cauto, precavido.

> precavido, da 1. adj. Sagaz, cauto, que sabe precaver los riesgos.

Si está esperando una mejor oferta, quiere postergar(estirar el elástico) esa decisión, no acepta presiones, no se autoimpone presión o no va a aventurarse a menos que esté seguro en ese nuevo entorno: Evasivo, evitativo.

> evasivo, va 2. f. Recurso para eludir una dificultad.

Si es por flojera: Ser dejado. "no lo hice por dejado"(dejadez).

> Laxitud Flojera, falta de fuerza o de tensión: laxitud muscular. Falta de severidad y disciplina, relajación moral: laxitud ética, educacional.